# CSS Triangle with smooth rounded adges

Tags: html, css

I am facing new and hardest css challenge for me. i need to develop an triangle box with icon and text. i have tried many different approaches but i failed to achieve the result i wanted to. please see image what i need. any suggestions or code would be appreciated.
[image]

```
<div class="outer-triangle">
    <div class="inner-triangle">
        <i class="fa fa-bathtub">
        <h2>Heading</h2>
        <p>This is testing for multi line paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've attempted?

Comment: i deleted all the code nothing works for me what i tired. can you please give a try for me? please

Answer (score -1):

The best I can get with pure CSS is as follow:

[image]

You can play with the code further to see if you can get it any further from here.

```js
let empty ='';
```

```css
.roundTriangle {
  background: #006600;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 20px solid #006600;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.roundTriangle::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  bottom: -62px;
  left: -13.9px;
  border: 24px solid transparent;
  border-top: 30px solid #006600;
}
```

```html
<div class="roundTriangle"></div>
```

Comment: Whoever down voted, at least have guts to give a proper reason?